# Hadoop Installation: no jobtracker to stop no namenode to stop

Tags: hadoop

Hadoop-0.20.2 Single Node Setup FAIL!!!! The jobtracker and namenode do not start :( 
Any suggestions would be welcome. 
As far as i know, i have set core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml and mapred-site.xml correctly

Answer (score 1):

assuming this question to be still unanswered, did you format your namenode directory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's simply not enough information in this question to provide any guidance.  Consider providing more detail and the contents of the relative configuration files to the Apache Hadoop user lists.